Colcon Build cause Windows error
I have just installed ros2 Jazzy on Winodows, when I try to run
colcon build --merge-install

I get the following error
WNDPROC return value cannot be converted to LRESULT
TypeError: WPARAM is simple, so must be an int object (got NoneType)

I get the same error regardless of the type of the package python/cpp and regardless of the code within the package nodes,
what could be the problem and How to overcome this problem?
